# Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Failed to start Node process

Tags: jss

getting the below error at Experience editor for Home item.

```
Error Rendering Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JsLayoutRenderer: Failed to start Node process. To resolve this: [1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories. Current PATH environment variable is: C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Airtame;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH. [2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance..ctor(String entryPointScript, String projectPath, String[] watchFileExtensions, String commandLineArguments, ILogger nodeOutputLogger, IDictionary`2 environmentVars, Int32 invocationTimeoutMilliseconds, Boolean launchWithDebugging, Int32 debuggingPort, String nodePath)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.Http.HttpNodeInstance..ctor(NodeServicesOptions options, Int32 port)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.NodeServicesOptions.<.ctor>b__3_0()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.GetOrCreateCurrentNodeInstance()
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExportWithPossibleRetry[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args, Boolean allowRetry)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.DefaultNodeServices.InvokeExport[T](String moduleName, String exportedFunctionName, Object[] args)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.NodeRenderEngine.Invoke[T](String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.PerformRender(TextWriter writer, IRenderEngine renderEngine, String moduleName, String functionName, Object[] functionArgs)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Presentation.JssRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
Inner Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.NodeServices.HostingModels.OutOfProcessNodeInstance.LaunchNodeProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the path to your `node.exe` can't be found in the system/environment `PATH` variable. You need to ensure that the path to wherever you installed Node.js is added to the `PATH` variable. For instance, if Node is installed at `c:\program files\nodejs`, then that value needs to be added to the system/environment `PATH` variable.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10

---

If you're not able to edit/modify the `PATH` variable on the Sitecore server, you can instruct the JSS Node engine to look for `node.exe` at a specific location. By default, the JSS Node engine will use your `PATH` variable. That setting is declared in this file on a Sitecore instance (with JSS installed): `App_Config/Sitecore/JavaScriptServices/Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Node.config`

You'll see the `/configuration/sitecore/javaScriptServices/renderEngines/renderEngine/instance/NodePath` value is `node` by default. You can directly modify this setting to an absolute file path on the server. Or better, patch the config file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <javaScriptServices>
      <renderEngines>
        <renderEngine name="nodejs">
          <instance id="defaults">
            <NodePath>c:\path\to\node</NodePath>
          </instance>
        </renderEngine>
      </renderEngines>
    </javaScriptServices>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

You should only modify this config setting if you're unable to change the `PATH` variable or if you have a very specific reason to do so.

Comment: Hello @Adam Weber, thanks for sharing the info. I have un install node.js and did re install again. After that error is fixed.

Comment: Yes, typically the Node installer for Windows will add the appropriate path the `PATH` environment variable.